# Change order of axes drawn in matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a figure in matplotlib where two axes overlap one-another. The axes draw according to the order in which they were created in the code, as shown when I print `fig.axes`, which returns `[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000021C7417B320>, <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000021C72371630>]`. I would like to change the order so that the second axes created draws first. The property `fig.axes` is not writeable, so I unfortunately can't create a new list with the order I need and then assign it. I've also tried using `ax.set_zorder()` where I specified `ax1.set_zorder(0)` and `ax2.set_zorder(1)`, but this did not work, and neither did the reverse or larger integer values. I can't seem to find anything in the documentation that would allow me to change the order in which axes are drawn, does anyone know of a way?

**Purpose**
As you can see, the grey year labels along the x-axis are covered by the black date call-outs. The year labels are part of ax1 and the date labels ax2. I'd like to switch the order so that ax1 is drawn above ax2, so as to not cover the year text.

[image]

Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Comment: have you tried changing the zorder of the labels instead of the axes?

Comment: Setting zorder should work. If it doesn't, feel free to provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Ah, I think I was trying to set it the wrong way - it works when using `ax2.zorder = 1` but when using `ax2.set_params(axis='x', zorder=1)` or `ax2.set_zorder()` it does not work, thank you!

Comment: It's simply `ax.set_zorder(1)` as you wrote in the question.